# Issue when running the Echidna fuzzer with Etheno trace (init.json)

Tags: echidna

I'm following the echidna official documentation for End to End testing as in here;
https://github.com/crytic/building-secure-contracts/blob/master/program-analysis/echidna/advanced/end-to-end-testing.md

I was able to capture the etheno trace into a init.json file for my contract deployments (Upgradeable) and then running a test.

However, when trying to replay it with

```
% echidna . --contract EchidnaE2E --config echidna.config.yaml
```

I'm getting the below set of errors;

```
[2023-09-13 12:20:00.58] Compiling .... Done! (22.453457s)
Analyzing contract: /Users/Chamara/ANZ/anz-cross-chain/blockchain/contracts/echidna/EchidnaE2E.sol:EchidnaE2E
echidna: Internal error: Call target doesn't exist -- CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  internalError, called at src/EVM.hs:1288:9 in hevm-0.51.3-AoN9URJtMgjJhononiOAyj:EVM
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/EVM/Types.hs:1273:19 in hevm-0.51.3-AoN9URJtMgjJhononiOAyj:EVM.Types
  internalError, called at src/EVM.hs:1288:9 in hevm-0.51.3-AoN9URJtMgjJhononiOAyj:EVM
```

What should be the solution for this?